# Reposition nodes in a multi-foci d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have three sets of nodes in a multi-foci force layout. Each node is already rendered in HTML.

Here's what my force layout code looks like:

```
var node = this.svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(data);

// foci is a dictionary that assigns the x and y value based
// on what group a node belongs to.
var foci = {
    "Blue" : {
         "x" : xScale(0),
         "y": height / 2
    },
    "Red": {
         "x" : xScale(1),
         "y": height / 2
    },
    "Purple": {
         "x" : xScale(2),
         "y": height / 2
    },
};

// This helped me position the nodes to their assigned clusters.
var forceX = d3.forceX((d) => foci[d.group].x);
var forceY = d3.forceY((d) => foci[d.group].y);

var force = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .force('x', forceX)
    .force('y', forceY)
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(8))
    .on('tick', function() {
         node
            .attr('transform', (d) => {
                return 'translate(' + (d.x - 100) + ',' + (-d.y + 25) + ')';
            });
        });
```

What I have been able to accomplish so far is redraw the layouts based on a change in the dropdown, which reinitilizes `d3.forceSimulation()` and makes the clusters snap back on the page, as you can see in the gif below.

That is not what I want. I'm trying to make the rearranging as seamless as possible.

UPDATE: By not reinitializing the `d3.forceSimulation()`, I can bind the new data to the nodes and change their colors.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of reinitialising `d3.forceSimulation()` you can simply *reheat* the simulation, using [`restart()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_restart):

> Restarts the simulation’s internal timer and returns the simulation. In conjunction with simulation.alphaTarget or simulation.alpha, this method can be used to “reheat” the simulation during interaction, such as when dragging a node, or to resume the simulation after temporarily pausing it with simulation.stop.

I created a demo to show you, using parts of your code. In this demo, the button randomizes the color of each data point. After that, we reheat the simulation:

```
force.alpha(0.8).restart();
```

Check it, clicking "Randomize":

```js
var width = 500, height = 200;

var svg = d3.select("#svgdiv")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);
 
var data = d3.range(100).map(function(d, i){
 return {
 group: Math.random()*2 > 1 ? "blue" : "red",
 id: i
 }
});

var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
 .domain([0, 1])
 .range([100, width-100]);

var foci = {
    "blue" : {
         "x" : xScale(0),
         "y": height / 2
    },
    "red": {
         "x" : xScale(1),
         "y": height / 2
    }
};

var forceX = d3.forceX((d) => foci[d.group].x);
var forceY = d3.forceY((d) => foci[d.group].y);

var node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", (d)=>d.group);


var force = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .velocityDecay(0.65)
    .force('x', forceX)
    .force('y', forceY)
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(8));
  
force.nodes(data)
    .on('tick', function() {
         node
            .attr('transform', (d) => {
                return 'translate(' + (d.x) + ',' + (d.y) + ')';
            });
        });
    
d3.select("#btn").on("click", function(){
    data.forEach(function(d){
  d.group = Math.random()*2 > 1 ? "blue" : "red"
  })
  node.transition().duration(500).attr("fill", (d)=>d.group);
  setTimeout(function(){
  force.nodes(data);
  force.alpha(0.8).restart();
  }, 1500)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Randomize</button>
<div id="svgdiv"><div>
```

PS: I put the *reheat*  inside a `setTimeout`, so you can first see the circles changing colours and, then, moving to the foci positions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is definitely a step in the right direction. I implemented your suggestions, but it's still not working for me. I'm still getting the "swooping" when I update the force simulation with the dropdown.

The difference between your demo and mine, I believe, is the data. You're randomizing the groups within the same data bound to a circle. In my case, I'm getting a brand new array of objects.

Comment: Well, the snippet shows clearly that my code works... anyway, I hope someone else solves your problem. Cheers.

Comment: Now I see. So, your new data can have a different length, is that correct? In that scenario, I believe you can use a key to keep what we call "object constancy".

Comment: If the lengths are the same, there is a very easy workaround: compare the old data array with the new data array, in a simple for loop, and change the objects of the old data array accordingly. Then, use my code to reheat the simulation.