# How to reposition nodes and translate them to another foci?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

im new to D3 and love it so far, I was playing around with multi foci force layout and got a part of what I want to do working fine, What I would like to know if its possible to reposition some of the node based on a time scale.
What I meant by that is currently what you see is 6(orange), 5(blue) and 3 (green) nodes in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spiritualcrisis/po12jdxy/9/) I created, So I want them to position themselves by translating towards each other i.e on day two data could be 5(orange), 6(blue) and 4(green), that means one orange node moves to green cluster.

```js
var data = [
  {"id": 0, "name": "x", "r":5 },
  {"id": 0, "name": "x", "r":5 },
  {"id": 0, "name": "x", "r":5 },
  {"id": 0, "name": "x", "r":5 },
  {"id": 0, "name": "x", "r":5 },

  {"id": 1, "name": "y", "r":5 },
  {"id": 1, "name": "y", "r":5 },
  {"id": 1, "name": "y", "r":5 },
  {"id": 1, "name": "y", "r":5 },
  {"id": 1, "name": "y", "r":5 },
  {"id": 1, "name": "y", "r":5 },

  {"id": 2, "name": "z", "r":5 },
  {"id": 2, "name": "z", "r":5 },
  {"id": 2, "name": "z", "r":5 },
];

var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = 410;

var fill = d3.scale.category10();

var nodes = [], labels = [],
    foci = [{x: 0, y: 10}, {x: 100, y: 210}, {x: 600, y: 210}];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", height)
    //.attr("domflag", '');

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links([])
    .charge(-10)
    //.chargeDistance(100)
    .gravity(0.1)
    .friction(0.8)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

//var node = svg.selectAll("circle");
var node = svg.selectAll("g");

var counter = 0;

function tick(e) {
  var k = .1 * e.alpha;

  // Push nodes toward their designated focus.
  nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.y += (foci[o.id].y - o.y) * k;
    o.x += (foci[o.id].x - o.x) * k;
  });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

}


var timer = setInterval(function(){

  if (nodes.length > data.length-1) { clearInterval(timer); return;}

  var item = data[counter];
  nodes.push({id: item.id, r: item.r, name: item.name});
  force.start();

  node = node.data(nodes);

  var n = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .on('mousedown', function() {
         var sel = d3.select(this);
         //``sel.moveToFront();
      })
      .call(force.drag);

  n.append("circle")
      .attr("r",  function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.id); })

  n.append("text")
      .text(function(d){
          return d.name;
      })
      .style("font-size", function(d) {
          return Math.min(2 * d.r, (2 * d.r - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength() * 16) + "px"; 
       })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")

  counter++;
}, 100);
```

```css
node {
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  .node:hover circle {
    fill: grey !important;
  }
  
  text {
    font: 18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;;
    text-anchor: middle;
    pointer-events: none;
    fill: white;
  }
  circle {
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: white ;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<h2>D3.js Multi-Foci Force layout </h2>
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spiritualcrisis/po12jdxy/9/) here.
What I want to know is how to translate nodes to another cluster and format data for looping through time.
I'm using D3 V3 for development.

Comment: Too bad you're using D3 v3... have a look at this (v4/5): https://stackoverflow.com/a/40414382/5768908. I reckon you'll have a hard time getting a v3 answer...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yup kinda realised this.. Im looking into it now. thanks for your comment